# NLP - How to detect sentence validity

Tags: nlp

We have sentences like:

- We need to talk to you on this subject important issue immediately.
- What year is this year?
- Anticipate talk to you

By reading these sentences, it's understandable that they are wrong.
What's the relevant field of studies in NLP that I need to look into, to understand how to detect these issues? (given a sentence like this -> classify it as incorrect)

Answer (score 2):

This is related to [language modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model).

A language model can predict the likelihood of a sentence after being trained on a large corpus of sentences. A language model does not deal with the semantics of the sentence, it can only assess how plausible the sentence is from a statistical point of view.